# I'm having problems with one-hot encoding

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I am using logistic regression for a football dataset, but it seems when i try to one-hot encode the home team names and away team names it gives the model a 100% accuracy, even when doing a train_test_split i still get 100. What am i doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.linear_model 
import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("FIN.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df[(df["Date"] > '2020/04/01')]
df['BTTS'] = np.where((df.HG > 0) & (df.AG > 0), 1, 0)
#print(df.to_string())
df.dropna(inplace=True)
x = df[['Home', 'Away', 'Res', 'HG', 'AG', 'PH', 'PD', 'PA', 'MaxH', 'MaxD', 'MaxA', 'AvgH', 'AvgD', 'AvgA']].values
y = df['BTTS'].values

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
model = LogisticRegression()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=[df.Home, df.Away, df.Res], sparse=False)
x = ohe.fit_transform(x)
print(x)
model.fit(x, y)
print(model.score(x, y))
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, shuffle=False)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(model.score(x_test, y_test))
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print("accuracy:", 
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("precision:", precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("recall:", recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("f1 score:", f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: Hard to say anything here, as nobody can run this code without the actual dataset!

Comment: Sounds like data leakage. Share your FIN.csv file

Comment: Isn't 'res' the score of the game and 'BTTS' whether both teams score?  That seems like something that would be 100% mappable (i.e. a 1-3 score is always true, a 0-3 score always false, and in most games there's going to be a much smaller subset of scores to possible games).

Comment: The one hot encoded features tend to have high colinearity and may overfit, It is advisable to drop one of the columns in one-hot encoding, you can achieve this by `OneHotEncoder(drop='first')` when you initialize the preprocessor.

Comment: @DanielF yes it is.

Comment: @darthbaba Ok, i just tried out your suggestion and i still get 100 without training and testing, but when i use it i get 89% accuracy, precision 100%, recall 76% and f1 score 87%. Is this still a sign of overfitting?

Comment: @chitown88 here's the link: https://www.football-data.co.uk/new/FIN.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overfitting would be a situation where your training accuracy is very high, and your test accuracy is very low. That means it's "over fitting" because it essentially just learns what the outcome will be on the training, but doesn't fit well on new, unseen data.

The reason you are getting 100% accuracy is precisely as I stated in the comments, there's a (for lack of a better term) data leakage. You are essentially allowing your model to "cheat". Your target variable `y` (which is `'BTTS'`) is feature engineered by the data. It is derived from `'HG'` and `'AG'`, and thus are highly (100%) correlated/associated to your target. You define `'BTTS'` as 1 when both `'HG'` and `'AG'` are greater than 1. And then you have those 2 columns included in your training data. So the model simply picked up that obvious association (Ie, when the home goals is 1 or more, and the away goals are 1 or more -> Both teams scored).

Once the model sees those 2 values greater than 0, it predicts 1, if one of those values is 0, it predicts 0.

Drop `'HG'` and '`AG`' from the x (features).

Once we remove those 2 columns, you'll see a more realistic performance (albeit poor - slightly better than a flip of the coin) here:

```
1.0
0.5625
accuracy: 0.5625
precision: 0.6666666666666666
recall: 0.4444444444444444
f1 score: 0.5333333333333333
```

With the Confusion Matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
labels = labels = np.unique(y).tolist()
cf_matrixGNB = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=labels)


import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.heatmap(cf_matrixGNB, annot=True, 
             cmap='Blues')

ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix\n');
ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Another option would be to do a calculated field of `'Total_Goals'`, then see if it can predict on that. Obviously again, it has a little help in the obvious (if `'Total_Goals'` is 0 or 1, then `'BTTS'` will be 0.). But then if `'Total_Goals'` is 2 or more, it'll have to rely on the other features to try to work out if one of the teams got shut out.

Here's that example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("FIN.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df[(df["Date"] > '2020/04/01')]
df['BTTS'] = np.where((df.HG > 0) & (df.AG > 0), 1, 0)
#print(df.to_string())
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['Total_Goals'] = df['HG'] + df['AG']

x = df[['Home', 'Away', 'Res', 'Total_Goals', 'PH', 'PD', 'PA', 'MaxH', 'MaxD', 'MaxA', 'AvgH', 'AvgD', 'AvgA']].values
y = df['BTTS'].values

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
model = LogisticRegression()

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
x = ohe.fit_transform(x)
#print(x)
model.fit(x, y)
print(model.score(x, y))
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, shuffle=False)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(model.score(x_test, y_test))
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print("accuracy:", 
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("precision:", precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("recall:", recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("f1 score:", f1_score(y_test, y_pred))

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
labels = np.unique(y).tolist()
cf_matrixGNB = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=labels)


import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.heatmap(cf_matrixGNB, annot=True, 
             cmap='Blues')

ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix\n');
ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

```
1.0
0.8
accuracy: 0.8
precision: 0.8536585365853658
recall: 0.7777777777777778
f1 score: 0.8139534883720929
```

[image]

To Predict on new data, you need the new data in the form of the training data. You then also need to apply any transformations you fit on the trianing data, to transform on the new data:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame(
        data = [['Haka', 'Mariehamn', 3.05,     3.66,   2.35,   3.05,   3.66,   2.52,   2.88,   3.48,   2.32]],
        columns = ['Home', 'Away', 'PH', 'PD', 'PA', 'MaxH', 'MaxD', 'MaxA', 'AvgH', 'AvgD', 'AvgA']
        )

to_predcit = new_data[['Home', 'Away', 'PH', 'PD', 'PA', 'MaxH', 'MaxD', 'MaxA', 'AvgH', 'AvgD', 'AvgA']]

to_predict_encoded = ohe.transform(to_predcit)
prediction = model.predict(to_predict_encoded)
prediction_prob = model.predict_proba(to_predict_encoded)

print(f'Predict: {prediction[0]} with {prediction_prob[0][0]} probability.')
```

**Output:**

```
Predict: 0 with 0.8204957018099501 probability.
```

Comment: You really explained it well for me, your answer was really helpful, now i have another minor problem, how do i now make a prediction with any of the teams? The one hot encoded numbers are confusing me for selecting the home and away team and using them to make a prediction. I would love your guidance.

Comment: Give me some time, I can get back to you on how to do that.

Comment: So what do you mean by ` how do i now make a prediction with any of the teams`? Are you saying to predict if both teams will score if they go head to head?

Comment: To predict on a future game? Or to see what it predicted on this data set?

Comment: I would like to predict a future game. I'm really stuck right now

Comment: Give me an example of a future game to predict on. The key is you need to set up the data to look like your training data. Then you feed that new data into your model to predict.

Comment: And also, siunmce you are predicting on a future game, you'd only really want to trian on data that pertains to that. For example, `"Res"` is unknown for a future game, so you can;t include that in your training data.

Comment: Ok, let's use an example of Haka as the home team and mariehamn as the away team. Can you guide me on that?

Comment: well haka as home and Marieham as away is already in the training data. So I'm assuming the other fields will be different?

Comment: I've seen the updated answer, very nice explanation but can you please elaborate further on what you meant by "I'm assuming the other fields will be different?"

Comment: Sure. The “future” match you suggested already exists in the training data. So really, unless the other features are different (like PH, PD, etc), you’re not really predicting on a future match. Your just predicting on the past instance.

Comment: Your questions are really beyond the scope of this SO post. See if you can look up the basics of machine learning pipeline/work flow, as that’s what this is pertaining to.